# AngularJS : ng-repeat with uniques values in particular method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have one object like this

```
$scope.listvalues = [{ name:A, id:101 },

                     { name:B, id:102 },

                     { name:A, id:103 },

                     { name:C, id:101 },

                     { name:A, id:102 },

                     { name:B, id:103 }];
```

I need to print this object in following structure

```
name |101 | 102 |103 |
-----|----|-----|---------
 A   |YES | YES |YES |
-----|----|-----|------------
 B   |No  | YES |YES |
-----|----|-----|-----------
 C   |YES |  NO |NO  |
```

Here i need to print the Name "A" in unique and also need to indicate the A is available for which Id. Is it possible to do with angularjs ng-repeat?. Any one please suggest...

Comment: i don't think you should use ng-repeat in such scenario

Comment: It is possible, but you should format your data in a better way before. It'll be easier and more understandable

Comment: then how can we print the object values in above format. If the object is larger any way we need to use the ng-repeat is it right??

Comment: All solutions below suffer from performance/memory issues, especially when the table is sparse. I would rather write a custom directive to handle this case and add watcher for possible bindings.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you would have to write a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#filter) that changes the structure of your data to the following:

```
$scope.data = [
    {A: {'101': true, '102': true, '103': true}}, 
    {B: {'101': false, ...}},
    {C: ...}
]
```

And then you can write your table like this:

```
   <table>
     <tr>
       <th>name</th>
       <th ng-repeat="(column, value) in data[0]">{{column}}</th>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
       <td ng-repeat="(column, value) in data[0]">{{row[column] ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

---

Example filter:

```
yourModule.filter('makeNgRepeatable', function(){
    return function(oldStructure) {
       // Add code here to convert oldStructure to newStructure.
       return newStructure;
    }
});
```

In your controller, inject `makeNgRepeatableFilter` and do

```
$scope.data = makeNgRepeatableFilter([{ name:A, id:101 }, ...]);
```

Comment: Can you please give one example for filtering the data to the proper format?

Comment: Added an example filter.

Comment: Why do you want to implement a filter for this? Is the `map` function not sufficient?

Comment: @Rouby You could do this in multiple ways, I chose a filter because it's the Angular way of doing it. A separate filter allows easier unit testing of your app.

Comment: *filter - Selects a subset of items from array and returns it as a new array.* ... well kinda :p

Comment: @Rouby There are two types of filters in Angular: one is filtering arrays, the other is transforming input:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter

Comment: Well I always thought of filters to use them for interpolations or directives. To format output for the user. Not to transform the underlying data.

Comment: Ideally, you format the data in an easily usable structure on the server instead of writing a filter on the client, but if that's not possible, a stateless filter is a perfect way of restructuring data, as Angular does not re-execute the filter as long as the input doesn't change. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#stateful-filters (stateful is the opposite of stateless, the filter in my example is stateless)

Answer (score 0):

You can pack this into a table and then resolve with multiple `ng-repeat`s which cell is YES or NO.

Take a look at this plnkr, it demonstrates how this could be achieved.

http://plnkr.co/edit/QI8ZrsbwYuJUeV4DNWGl?p=preview

First you collect all distinct *ids* and *names*.

```
$scope.names = $scope.listvalues.map(function(d){return d.name}).unique();
$scope.ids = $scope.listvalues.map(function(d){return d.id}).unique();
```

Note: In the plnkr I defined the functions `unique` and `contains`. If you use some other libraries like underscore those functions may already be present.

Then you define a function to determine if a specific cell should be true or false.

```
  $scope.hasValue = function(name, id)  {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.listvalues.length; ++i)
      if($scope.listvalues[i].name === name && $scope.listvalues[i].id === id)
        return true;
    return false;
  }
```

However, it would be simpler if you can convert your `listvalues` into a reasonable structure. This would prevent some of the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

With your array structure you might need some additional helper array/objects. In your case it could look like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th ng-repeat="th in values">{{th}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj in names">
            <td>
                {{obj.name}}
                <div><small>{{obj}}</small></div>
            </td>
            <td>{{obj.ids.indexOf(values[0]) > -1 ? 'YES' : 'NO'}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.ids.indexOf(values[1]) > -1 ? 'YES' : 'NO'}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.ids.indexOf(values[2]) > -1 ? 'YES' : 'NO'}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

where helper objects are constructed like:

```
function initData() {

    var map = {values: {}, names: {}},
        values = [],
        names = [];

    $scope.listvalues.forEach(function(obj) {
        if (!map.values[obj.id]) {
            values.push(obj.id);
            map.values[obj.id] = true;
        }

        if (!map.names[obj.name]) {
            names.push(obj);
            obj.ids = [obj.id];
            map.names[obj.name] = obj;
        }
        else {
            map.names[obj.name].ids.push(obj.id);
        }
    });

    $scope.values = values;
    $scope.names = names;
}

initData();
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/wWJOjtzstUDKjl9V6hCy?p=preview